# How can I disable the add event button in calendar portlet in liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I want to give permissions of adding event in calendar to some user and for some users it has to be disabled. How can I achieve it programatically ?

Comment: I have given permissions to Specific roles from calendar portlet's permission tab. but add event button is still enable for all the users. I havnt any idea about how to do it programatically.

Comment: You could hook the jsp and make the add button just visible in case of having that role

Comment: @jorge....But i cant find when and where add event button is added and how to disable it...

Comment: @VinitaShah: Please update your question on what you have tried with roles and permission, that will help everyone to understand the scenario?

Comment: @PankajkumarKathiriya :  I got the solution as i have posted it but I am trying to disable add event button only if manage events permission is not given to that user. but i cant find the condition for that.

Comment: calendar portlet is a plugin from LR6.2 on, and it is not in Liferay portal classloader anymore. You cannot hook its jsps the way we used to. You have to extend the calendar plugin. See https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-plugins-to-extend-plugins

Answer (score 1):

`showAddEventBtn = false;` will do the trick for you.

Put this line after `boolean showAddEventBtn = ParamUtil.getBoolean(request, "showAddEventBtn");` in `scheduler.jsp`

It will disable the add event Button..

Comment: Additionally, you can control this code, based on permission setup.

Comment: But I cant find the condition to check if user has given permission to manage events.. I have tried this condition,  CalendarPermission.contains(permissionChecker, userDefaultCalendar, ActionKeys.MANAGE_BOOKINGS)  But it is not working

Comment: Where are you setting this parameter?

Comment: You can try adding following lines in `view_calendar.jsp` before `viewCalendarBookingURL`:

`String showAddEventBtn = String.valueOf((userDefaultCalendar != null) && CalendarPermission.contains(permissionChecker, userDefaultCalendar, ActionKeys.MANAGE_BOOKINGS));

<liferay-util:param name="showAddEventBtn" value="<%= showAddEventBtn %>" />`

Comment: @prakash Kumar.....I have tried to put condition in view_calendar.jsp but It is not working...

Comment: Not working in a sense? Button is appearing or button is not appearing?

Comment: What does this condition evaluates?

Comment: I have written condition like , CalendarPermission.contains(permissionChecker, userDefaultCalendar, ActionKeys.MANAGE_BOOKINGS) For checking if it has manage_events Permission or not...But it is not evaluating properly..